# HOC to render wrapped component + additional component

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

Let's say I have dropdown list component, and when I choose "Other" option in that dropdown list, I reveal a text box to specify the option that isn't specified in the dropdown list choices.

So if want to create such component for different inputs for a form, can I use HOC? The following is my current code. How can I reuse this component without rewriting the same class for another input, let's say religion input? Is there other ways except extracting two FormItem into two components.

```
  export class NationalitySelect extends Component {
  state = { showFormInput: false };

  onSelect = (value) => {
    if (value === 'OT') {
      this.setState({ showFormInput: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ showFormInput: false });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { decorator } = this.props;
    const { showFormInput } = this.state;
    return (
      <FormItem {...layout} label="Nationality" colon required>
        <Col span={7}>
          <FormItem>
            {decorator('nationality', { initialValue: 'JP' })(
              <FormSelect onChange={value => this.onSelect(value)}>
                <Option value="JP">Japanese</Option>
                <Option value="SG">Singaporean</Option>
                <Option value="OT">Others</Option>
              </FormSelect>,
            )}
          </FormItem>
        </Col>
        {/* show text input if nationality is others */}
        {showFormInput && (
          <Col span={17}>
            <FormItem>
              {decorator('otherNationality', {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please specify your nationality!',
                  },
                ],
              })(<FormInput type="text" />)}
            </FormItem>
          </Col>
        )}
      </FormItem>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make it simple without all the complex html, but to show the way I think will work well and could get reused.

I would create a new extended `FormSelect` like

```
class ImprovedFormSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           isOther: false;
        }
    }

    onSelect(value) {
        if (value === 'OT') {
            this.setState({ isOther: true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ isOther: false });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FormSelect onChange={value => this.onSelect(value)}>
                    {this.props.options.map(opt =><Option value={opt.value}>Japanese</Option>)}

                    <Option value="OT">Others</Option>
                </FormSelect>

                {this.state.isOther && <FormInput type="text" />}
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

something in that area but surely it needs to work on.
But to use it, you just pass the options:

```
<ImprovedFormSelect
    options={[
         'Japanese',
         'Singaporean'
    ]}
/>
```